Question about bitcoin generating block time in book "mastering bitcoin " 3rd edtion
In book "mastering bitcoin" 3rd, chapter 2, page 27, there is a statement: Approximately 19 minutes after the block containing Alice’s transaction is broadcast, a new block is mined by another miner.
My question is why it is 19 minutes? i think it is about 10 minutes.
you can find this book by link below.
https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/BOOK.md
thanks.

It is talking about an actual block, mined on February 4th 2023, which took 19 minutes.
The average time between two blocks is, when the hashrate is stable, approximately 10 minutes. However, this is just an average. Even in theory, the time between blocks follows an Exponential Distribution, which has a range from 0 to infinity. In practice, more uncertainty is added to this due to the hashrate not being constant. Real inter-block times vary from seconds to over an hour.
